# Syntax error with ? operator in c++

Tags: c++

I am using the ? operator and i want to express the following

```
  (a > b) ? (max = a) : (); // basically i want expression after `:` to be null
```

If i leave empty brackets after `:` the compiler complains in-correct syntax. What is the correct syntax for leaving  expression after `:` empty?

Comment: Why don't you use a regular `if` statement then?

Comment: its basically for my learning and somehow i like to conciseness of code in ? operator

Comment: The ` ? : ` is called a TERTIARY operator. You can't leave off one of the parts. You need and `if` as has been suggested.

Comment: The ternary operator should not have side-effects. It's just "better" this way.

Comment: If you want the obscurity of `?:`, but with no third term, try `&&`: `(a>b)&&(max = a);`

Comment: You could just use `NULL`. It's generally defined to be 0. ;-)

Comment: @Omnifarious I do not think that will work unless `NULL` can be converted to the same type as `max`. So if `max` is a `CMyFrobThing`, you'll get an error.

Comment: @mrunion - it's **ternary**, not tertiary.

Comment: @PeteBecker, not according to Star Trek...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> i like to conciseness of code in ? operator

`if (a > b) max = a;` is more concise, if we're counting characters. Which is a terrible metric.

Ideally, your ternary operators should not cause side-effects. Hiding side-effects inside a ternary operator makes code harder to read/debug/maintain etc.

If you want side-effects, don't get the ternary operator involved.

If you wanted to use the ternary operator for the sake of it, consider `max = (a > b) ? a : max`.

Comment: The compiler will be smart enough to ignore `max = max` if `a <= b`.

Comment: @billz, that's a different behavior.

Comment: @Omnifarious Assuming `max = max` won't have side-effects.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That's true. I was making the unwarranted assumption that in this case max was of an integral type. Personally, I've come to like `(a>b)&&(max = a)` as the maximally obscure answer, though it fails to use the ternary operator so beloved of the OP.

Comment: @Omnifarious Just work it in... `((true?a:a)>(true?b:b))&&(max = (true?a:a))`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A).  it is of the form

```
   <condition> ? <r-value1> : <r-value2>
```

and it returns r-value1 if condition's true.  otherwise, it returns r-value2.

so one way to do what you want is:

```
  (a > b) ? (max = a) : 0;
```

0 is an r-value of the same type, so it's fine.

however, note that this is a *horrible* way to write code.  it's not very readable.

as a learning exercise, it's ok, but otherwise, as everyone says, use

```
  if (a>b) max=a;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a ternary operator and as far as it goes there isn't really a clean way to just leave it blank. There is a work around which would look like this:

```
(a > b)?max=a:max=max;
```

But that really isn't too too efficient. The most efficient way to approach it would be as @ta-speot-is mentioned, and use an abbreviated conditional statement instead of the ternary operator